# OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION, Error while inserting a CaseTeamMember using Trigger

Tags: trigger, community

I have a trigger which inserts a "CaseTeamMember" when we add a feed comment to a Case object. The issue is that once we login as a Community User and create a case with it and then try to add a feed comment we are getting the error :

> "FeedCommentTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION, You can't perform this operation with the selected user type.: [] Trigger.FeedCommentTrigger: line 61, column 1"

We have tried the following things :

- Made OWD of Case and Account Object to Public Read/Write
- Created a Without Sharing class and called it through the trigger
  In Helpdesk
- Created and Made Changes in Sharing Set of a Community
- Created a Case Team Member Role and Checked the Visible in Customer Portaloption
- Added Team Members in Predefined Case Team
- Checked all the Community User Related Profile
- Unchecked the "Chatter Answer User" option for the User related to the Community User Profile.

Please find the screenshot for the same.

So please let is know on ASAP the solution for the above issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normally this error occurs when `ownerid` is pointing to an inactive user. Can you share your code

Comment: Sorry, but I can't share the code. And secondly the user is a community user not an inactive user. I think so the Community user is causing such unwanted error.

Comment: is this working for internal users?

Comment: Yes It is working for internal users but if we create a case through a Community User and then add a comment to it by an internal user then again it gives the error.

Comment: Have you enabled cases for community? Please check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_enable_cases_for_external_users.htm

Comment: But I am able to create a Case by login through a community

Comment: Is case comment created by trigger.

Comment: Make sure it's an internal user before adding them to the team...clearly case teams and community users don't mix.

Comment: The trigger is on FeedComment(after insert). After inserting a comment a CaseTeamMember Record is created.

Comment: Hi ALl,
Any Solution for the above issue.

Comment: Depending on the user type, some users cannot be the owner of a record. Eg chatter free. Try change the owner to a regular user and storing the id of your community user in a text field. Apparently in lightning this restriction is lifted.